# X11 doesn't start after clean 11.10 install (Dell E6500, nvidia, 8Gb RAM, i386)

Tags: 11.10, xorg, nvidia, installation

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10, i386 on my Dell Latitude E6500.
The installation was fine, but then X11 didn't start.

/var/log/X.0.org says:

```
(EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
...
(EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to load NVIDIA kernel module!
```

I installed nvidia-current

```
apt-get install nvidia-current
```

but no luck.

Just in case: 10.10 works just fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "nv" driver was dropped from Ubuntu, in favor of the "nouveau" driver.  Check if you have a /etc/X11/xorg.conf file; if you do, see if it lists driver "nv"; if it does, change that to "nouveau" (or "nvidia" if you still have nvidia-current installed)

Btw, you probably should install t he nvidia driver using jockey-text or jockey-gtk, since that will also do some sanity checking, ensure xorg.conf is set right, update the kernel, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

```
sudo jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current
```

fixed it for me.

you can use 
     jockey-text --list 
to obtain the driver list.